# Android Nested Objects Json error

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to parse nested objects in json but i don't find a solution.

My Json is :

```js
{"status":"ok","response":
    {"1":[
        {"Albert 1er":{"id":"74400610","lat":"43.6165153431063","lon":"3.87407454752208","name":"Place Albert 1er","town":"Montpellier","lines":[]}},
        {"Antigone":{"id":"74401726","lat":"43.6085958455429","lon":"3.8866476240206","name":"Antigone","town":"Montpellier","lines":[]}}
    ]}
}
```

my code is :

```java
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);               
JSONArray stats = json.getJSONArray("response");

for (int j = 0; j < stats.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject c = stats.getJSONObject(j);
    // Storing each json item in variable
    String nom_station = c.getString("name");
    System.out.println(nom_station);
}
```

Comment: That JSON snippit is not complete, can you copy&paste it again, being careful about closing brackets?

Comment: the full JSON is in this link : http://modulaweb.fr/apitam/?request=getStopsList&fullInfos=1

Answer (score 0):

IMO best solution is using google Gson lib to do marshalling and dealing with JSON array that contains mixed types

```
Class Adresse {
String id;
float lat;
float lon;
Sring name;
String town;
Object lines[];
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(json, Adresse.class);
```

[Link::gson-user-guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types)

Comment: the result is null :/